# Convert content of file to JavaScript array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

So I know `file()` returns every new line into an array.

```
$plugins = file("plugins.txt");
foreach($plugins as $plugin) {
    echo $plugin;
 }
```

Which returns

```
item1 item2 item3
```

In one line. Though, I know PHP thinks it's an array, JS doesnt, if I convert the above PHP script into a function and then do:

```
var pluginsList = <?php echo filetoArray(); ?>;
```

Which returns in console

```
var pluginsList = item1 item2 item3
```

While I was hoping for:

```
var pluginsList = [item1,item2,item3];
```

How would I make sure it reutns an array so JS can read?

EDIT:
So thanks to the answers, I got an array finally. But it returns like this:

```
["item1\r\n","item2\r\n","item3\r\n","item4"]
```

Though, I want the \r\n to be removed. What I have so far: the str_replace doesn't do anything, it's the same.

```
    $plugins = file("plugins.txt");
    $plugins = json_encode($plugins);
    $plugins = str_replace("\n\r", "", $plugins);
    echo $plugins;
```

Comment: I believe something you are looking for is called JSON which gives the PHP the ability to pass PHP Code into JS, and JS into PHP

Comment: Sorry... tried to be descriptive as possible :/

Comment: make array and use `json_encode()`

Answer (score 4):

Easy as this:

```
$plugins = file("plugins.txt");
$plugins = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '', $plugins);
$output = json_encode($plugins);
print $output;
```

Comment: Thanks! Though now it's returning \n\r after every line, and rtrim() isn't removing is for some reason...............

Comment: @devs look at `nl2br();` if you want to convert the \n\r to a new line. else if you want it removed all together, use `str_replace("\n\r", "", $VarToReplacein);`

Comment: @ArmelLarcier your edit won't replace either, since `json_encode` will already convert the CR/LFs to escaped strings itself. Better to perform a `str_replace` before the encode: http://codepad.org/czjr2CHN